# Onclick Javascript Issue

Tags: javascript, custom-button

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/33.0/apex.js")} 

var rcn = "{!Opportunity.Description__c}"; 
var amt = "{!Opportunity.Amount}"; 
if( rcn!= '' && amt!= '' && amt!= '0.00') 
{ 
window.open("{!URLFOR( $Action.Opportunity.Submit, Opportunity.Id )}"); 
} 
else if (amt=='' || amt =='0.00') 
{ 
alert("Enter Amount"); 
} 
else if (rcn=='') 
{ 
alert("Enter Description"); 
} 
else 
{ 
alert("Enter Amount and Description"); 
}
```

Here my target is that I should be able to submit an opportunity for approval only if Amount and Description are entered. Else it should throw errors separately is any of those fields is null/zero. This code is alowing me to submit even though Amount is null and also Description is null.

Comment: Did you try to check what is the value of Amount and description when they are left blank? I reckon, it should be null, instead of blank space.

Comment: Yeah on the record, they are blank. In this code, I also tried adding the condition as rcn==null . But it still didn't work.

Comment: it is working for me can u specify the exact problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of minor issues. Let's fix it up:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/33.0/apex.js")}
```

Not required here. Remove these lines, as they're just causing additional loading time.

```
var rcn = "{!JSENCODE(Opportunity.Description__c)}";
```

Make sure you encode text values.

```
var amt = {!BLANKVALUE(Opportunity.Amount, 0)};
```

Use a real number, it's easier.

```
if(rcn && amt) {
```

Nulls, undefined values, empty strings and 0 is a "falsy" value, anything else is "truthy" value.

```
    window.open("{!JSENCODE(URLFOR( $Action.Opportunity.Submit, Opportunity.Id ))}");
```

Again, just a good habit, even though this is most likely safe.

```
} else if(!amt && !rcn) {
    alert("Enter Amount and Description"); 
} else if(!amt) {
    alert("Enter Amount"); 
} else {
    alert("Enter Description"); 
}
```

You have to check the most specific situations first. In the original code, !amt && !rcn could never be reached, because the less specific conditions would be met first.

---

Final version:

```
var rcn = "{!JSENCODE(Opportunity.Description__c)}"; 
var amt = {!BLANKVALUE(Opportunity.Amount, 0)}; 
if(rcn && amt) {
    window.open("{!JSENCODE(URLFOR( $Action.Opportunity.Submit, Opportunity.Id ))}"); 
} else if(!amt && !rcn) {
    alert("Enter Amount and Description"); 
} else if(!amt) {
    alert("Enter Amount"); 
} else {
    alert("Enter Description"); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the load performance point here. I have only one issue here. Field Opportunity.Description__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions. My Description field is a picklist field actually. I tried to put JSENCODE(TEXT(Opportunity.Description__c)) but it seems syntax error. Please let me know how to use picklist in JSEN function.

Comment: @user42273 Is it a multi-select field or single-select? It looks like it should be okay. Realistically, since all you're interested in is if there's a value or not, maybe you could use an expression like `var hasDescription = {!NOT(ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.Description__c,"")};` instead.

Comment: It is just a single picklist having three values. It gave me an error when using JSEN. I was not able to use ISPICKVAL in javascript earlier. Let me try if this works.